# Pandas: Separating list into different columns based on contents

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list:

```
brand_size = ['Brand:Ashfield Farm; Size / Weight:375g',
              'Size / Weight:170g',
              '',
              'Brand:Lacura; Size / Weight:750 ml',
              '',
              '',
              "Brand:Nature's Glen",
              '',
              '',
              '',
              'Brand:Ashfield Farm; Size / Weight:450g',
              'Brand:Specially Selected',
              'Brand:Specially Selected',
              '',
              '',
              '',
              '',
              '']
```

What I want: a dataframe that lists the "Brand" and "Size / Weight" if it has them, and leaves it blank if not. E.g.

```
pd.DataFrame({'Brand':['Ashfield Farm', '', '', 'Lacura', '', '', "Nature's 
                       Glen", '', '', '', 'Ashfield Farm', 'Specially 
                       Selected', 'Specially Selected', '', '', '', '', ''],
              'Size / Weight':['375g', '170g', '', '750ml', '', '', '', 
                               '','', '', '450g', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']})

                 Brand   Size / Weight
0        Ashfield Farm          375g
1                               170g
2                                   
3               Lacura         750ml
4                                   
5                                   
6        Nature's Glen              
7                                   
8                                   
9                                   
10       Ashfield Farm          450g
11  Specially Selected              
12  Specially Selected              
13                                  
14                                  
15                                  
16                                  
17
```

I'm having a hard time getting started on this one, any help?

Comment: Where is this list coming from?

Comment: Can you change the code that generates the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert brand_size to a dictionary of records and load it in a dataframe. Check below code. And make changes, where you seem fit

```
   dfdict = [dict(kv.split(':') for kv in e.split('; ') if kv) for e in brand_size]
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dfdict)
   df = df.fillna('')
```

Comment: `[dict(kv.split(':') for kv in e.split('; ') if kv) for e in brand_size]`